# Mouseover(show content) javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript, I wonder, how can I make this:
I have menu item, then you click on it, info box pops up, there's X in corner, you close it and that's it. But my goal is not only on click show it, but even then you hover it. Here's script, if you need CSS let me know.

```
$('#help').appendTo('.navbar-container .level1');
$('#help a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#help').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#help').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#help').addClass('active');
    }
    $('#help-block').toggle();
});
$('#help-block .help-close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#help-block').css('display','none');
    $('#help').removeClass('active');
});
```

Thanks, people! Happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple events can be bound to one `.on()` method, e.g:

```
$('#help a').on('click hover', function(e) {
    // continue
});
```

> **Description:** Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Ref: [.on() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Consider using this method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` and `mouseover` like this:

```
$('#help').appendTo('.navbar-container .level1');
$('#help a').on("click mouseover",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#help').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#help').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#help').addClass('active');
    }
    $('#help-block').toggle();
});
$('#help-block .help-close').on("click mouseover",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#help-block').css('display','none');
    $('#help').removeClass('active');
});
```